# error:areq Bad Argument Argument 'PanelController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my Html

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
   ...........
    <section  ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills"">
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(1)}">
            <a href="#" ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Description</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(2)}">
            <a href="#" ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Specification</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(3)}">
            <a href="#" ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Reviews</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)" >
          <h4>Description</h4>
          <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
          <h4>Specification</h4>
          <p>Enter the product specification here</p>
         </div>
         <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)">
           <h4>Review</h4>
           <p>Product review goes here.</p>
         </div>
    </section>
   </div>
<body>
```

this is my Js file and the problem I came across is after adding PanelController,but I could not find the whats wrong with it

```
(function(){
    var app= angular.module("store",[]);
    app.controller("StoreController", function(){
       this.products = gems;
    });
    app.controller("PanelController", function(){
        this.tab = 1;
        this.selectTab = function(setTab){
            this.tab = setTab;
        };
        this.isSelected = function(checkedTab){
            return this.tab === checkedTab;
        };
    });
    var gems=[
    {
        name:'Ruby',
        price:1000000,
        description:'It originally .......... ',    
        images:
        {
            thumb:'red.jpg',
            full :'blue.jpg'
        },

        canPurchase:true,
    },
    .......
    ]

})();
```

This error appeared when I added the PanelController, can anyone help me on this?
thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is almost always related to the fact, that

1. your controller is in some module which is not part of the root module named in **`ng-app`**, or
2. the `.js` containing it *(controller)* is not loaded.

Here I've taken your snippets - and they are working as they are:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WUeFelbaMrrRebQZjpWg?p=info

The only extend with ng-app like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
   <head>...</head>
   <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
   ...
```

Comment: thanx, I had same filename in two different location and I had loaded the other one.

Comment: Does it mean it is working now? If yes, then great ;) ;)

Comment: Yes it is. The 2nd fact that you mentioned was the problem.